# bundler: failed to load command: fastlane

Tags: ruby, jenkins, rubygems, bundler, fastlane

This is the output of fastlane env command when I run with Jenkins.

SDK and fastlane setup is in Docker Container.

```
[09:11:28]: [33mGet started using a Gemfile for fastlane https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#use-a-gemfile[0m
`/` is not writable.
Bundler will use `/tmp/bundler20200228-96-c24ujz96' as your home directory temporarily.

/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:232:in `mkdir': [31m[!] Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /.fastlane[0m (Errno::EACCES)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:232:in `fu_mkdir'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:208:in `reverse_each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:208:in `block in mkdir_p'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:193:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:193:in `mkdir_p'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/fastlane-2.141.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/module.rb:28:in `fastlane_user_dir'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/fastlane-2.141.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/analytics/analytics_session.rb:58:in `did_show_message?'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/fastlane-2.141.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/analytics/analytics_session.rb:22:in `action_launched'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/fastlane-2.141.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:74:in `run!'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/delegates.rb:15:in `run!'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/fastlane-2.141.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:349:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/fastlane-2.141.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:41:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/fastlane-2.141.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:119:in `take_off'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/fastlane-2.141.0/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/fastlane:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/fastlane:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I have the same issue

Comment: @Prejith P did you fix the `Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /.fastlane[0m (Errno::EACCES)` issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a fastlane lane in a docker image on Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61735040/how-to-run-a-fastlane-lane-in-a-docker-image-on-jenkins)

Comment: No @ThomasKoppensteiner

Comment: @AWSCoder did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @Jkrist Not yet

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the following env vars in your Dockerfile:

```
GEM_HOME=/bundle

ENV BUNDLE_PATH $GEM_HOME
ENV BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG=$BUNDLE_PATH \
  BUNDLE_BIN=$BUNDLE_PATH/bin
ENV PATH $BUNDLE_BIN:$PATH
```

Then when you run `bundle` it should use the correct directory to install into.